# Insert reference column from another table

Tags: sql

I'm currently using simple script to create a new record into a table.

```
insert into PRODUCT(name,color) values('product1','red');
```

But what if we change our table structure, ie. the column "color" will no longer be a varchar but a reference id, and all the color will be maintained in a seperate table, and we just need to insert a reference id form that color table, how can I handle and update my insert sql as well as the query by specific color ?

Answer (score 0):

In case of SQL Server, if your `Product` table is not an in-memory table then you can add a new column to it with:

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCT ADD ColorID int
```

Then you just issue an `UPDATE` to populate the corresponding ID's for colors in the new `ColorID` column of the `Product` table.

```
UPDATE P
SET P.ColorID = C.ID
FROM PRODUCT P
    INNER JOIN COLORS C ON P.COLOR = C.ColorName
```

Then if you really want to, you can drop the old `COLOR` column and rename the current `ColorID` column to `Color`.

**But, you should plan for this ahead of time**. And generally, a color table makes much more sense.